# Is protobuf only technique getting used in grpc?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Are there some other formats available which we can use instead of protobuf in grpc?

Answer (score 1):

The gRPC stack has no strict dependency on the marshaller/serializer being used. All that gRPC sees is a binary buffer, with entirely opaque contents (it doesn't even specify a content-type header), sent over HTTP/2 routes.

***By convention***, gRPC is described by a .proto schema, which defines the gRPC methods and the payload messages, which then generates binding code using protocol buffers for the marshaller/serializer.

However, if you're willing to write the binding code yourself (or use a library that does), you can register gRPC endpoints using your own marshaller/serializer. The exact details of how to do this will vary between platforms/languages/libraries, but yes: it is possible. Since no metadata (headers, etc) is used to resolve the marshaller/serializer, both client and server must agree **in advance** what format is going to be used for the payload.

Answer (score 0):

The gRPC protocol is agnostic to the marshaller/IDL, but Protocol Buffers is the only marshaller directly supported by gRPC.

I'm aware of [Flatbuffers](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-flatbuffers/) and [Bond](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_over_grpc.html) supporting gRPC. There are probably others.

You are free to support your own favorite format. It isn't easy, but it isn't hard; it mainly involves glue code and defining the RPC schema for gRPC to use. The [gRPC + JSON gRPC blog post](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json/) walks through the process for grpc-java. Each language is a bit different and has to be supported individually.